# Is there a way of defining infinity so that it both meets the criterion of being a number as well as being greater than any real number?

Tags: infinity

This number would not be equivalent to the concept of infinity, but would be a number analogous to that concept. I'd also be interested to how the different ways of doing this (I'm assuming there are many), how they differ, and what their different applications are.

So this version of infinity would behave like this:

$\infty$ > X for all X $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

$\infty$ + 2 > $\infty$ + 1

2 > 1

Rather than:

$\infty$ is the largest number

$\infty$ + 2 = $\infty$ + 1

2 = 1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

Comment: Perhaps look for a non-standard analysis textbook...

Comment: I mean, you can just add element $\infty$, with the addition properties you mentioned, but then subtraction breaks (which is why you can't go from $\infty+1=\infty+2$ to $1=2$). So, are you willing to let go of subtraction to allow for infinity?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think cardinals are better suited for OP's purposes as they maintain commutativity.

Comment: @DonThousand But with cardinals, you lose the idea of $\infty + 2 > \infty + 1$, which seemed to be the important idea in the question.  Of course, either ordinal or cardinal numbers might be on the right track.  On the other hand, perhaps the hyperreal or surreal numbers would answer the question?

Comment: @XanderHenderson OP seems to like the idea of $\infty+1=\infty+2$ though. I doubt hyperreals and surreals would do the trick for OP as you make even more sacrifices to nice properties, which OP seems to view as intuitive.

Comment: @DonThousand Perhaps I am confused, by my reading of the question is that the asker *does not* like the idea of $\infty+1 = \infty+2$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Re-reading it, I'm not sure anymore. Does OP like it? OP seems to assume it, at least.

Comment: @Don Thousand You don't need to let subtraction go, but you do need to let $\infty - \infty = 0$ go. $\infty - \infty = \theta$ where $\theta + x = \theta$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ works.

Comment: In other words, you need to add 2 new elements; 1) $\infty$, which is greater than any real number and 2) $\theta$, which "absorbs" all real numbers, that is given any real number and any function involving $\theta$, returns $\theta$.

Comment: Then again this works for any number with any paradoxical properties so it is kinda trivial

Comment: @SenZen There is no ordered field containing the reals with precisely one infinity (or even finitely many, as far as I know). When OP uses the $\infty$ symbol, that to me indicates that OP wants a system with a uniquely identifiable infinity that adjoins onto the already present real field. One can't do this without breaking subtraction, or at least, taking away the properties that we know of subtraction.

Comment: What about homogeneous/projective co-ordinates?

Comment: @DonThousand OP didn't ask for a field that contains _only_ the standard reals plus this new $\infty$ element?

Comment: This 2 variable approach (called a wheel algebra), obeys all the desired properties listed by OP.

Comment: @SenZen I'm aware of wheel algebras. They don't invalidate my claim, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Don Thousand Then that proves your claim is not relevant to OP's question. A wheel algebra obeys all 3 properties of OP.

Answer (score 9):

There are indeed lots of ways to do this, although they may not quite paint the picture you expect.

At the simplest level, assuming that you want a number system in which addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division work "as we expect," you're just looking for **non-Archimedean ordered fields** which contain $\mathbb{R}$. There are indeed lots of these. For example, consider the set of rational functions in a single variable $x$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{R}$, modulo equality almost everywhere (so that we identify e.g. $x$ with $x^2\over x$). This is a field, and carries a natural ordering compatible with the field structure: set $f<g$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(g(x)-f(x))>0$. It's easy to check that this is in fact a non-Archimedean field. (In fact, note that any ordered field containing $\mathbb{R}$ must be non-Archimedean!)

- A powerful result here is the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) from logic. This implies that, in a precise sense, whenever I have a "reasonably concrete" set of algebraic properties describing some (infinite) structure there are other structures satisfying those same properties which are "as big as I want" (e.g. cardinality $2^{2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}}$ instead of $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=2^{\aleph_0}$). That's overkill here, but it's a good thing to keep in mind for down the road. (Note that this, combined with the previous paragraph, means that Archimedean-ness is *not* a "reasonably concrete" property in the relevant sense!)

We can look further for non-Archimedean fields satisfying additional special properties. A *hyperreal field*, for example, is a non-Archimedean ordered field which shares *all* "reasonably-definable" properties with $\mathbb{R}$ [in a precise sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis), while the *surreal numbers* form a particular (proper-class-sized) non-Archimedean ordered field which is "maximal" in [an appropriate sense](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/%7Ermiller/Ehrlich.pdf).

In all such cases however there is not a single "distinguished" infinite element; instead, there are *lots* of infinite elements, with no one being particularly special. So this cuts against the idea of $\infty$ as a meaningful symbol denoting a single element.

Comment: As an aside, I think it's worth mentioning now a *negative* result, that is, a nice property which $\mathbb{R}$ has - which is not phrased in terms of infinities - which no non-Archimedean field has and in fact which characterizes $\mathbb{R}$ completely up to isomorphism. Namely, $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique-up-to-isomorphism ordered field which is *connected* in the sense of topology. In fact we don't even need the full field structure for this: $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique connected ordered *group*. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3937942/28111) for some comments on this point.

Comment: I'm a particular fan of the hyperreals, as they seem a very natural extension to the reals.  It allows us to take our intuitions about arithmetic and continue them on to infinity.  It solves many issues with divergent series and the like.  If you taught hyperreals in high school then calculus is just algebra.

Comment: @johnnyb Careful though - there is no such thing as "the" hyperreals. Rather, there are many different *hyperreal fields*, and in contrast with $\mathbb{R}$ there's no one which is obviously distinguished. This is one reason, in my opinion anyways, that they're less foundationally satisfying (although again this isn't universal by any means).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree. I also disagree with the premise that hyperreals make calculus into algebra, as I think that people over think the "fraction" behavior of derivatives. Thinking of derivatives as infinitesimal fractions will crash and burn somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

As Noah says there are a bunch of inequivalent ways to do this depending on what properties of ordinary arithmetic you want to preserve. Here's what happens when you try to add a single infinite element.

Starting with the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (or the integers or whatever else) you can add a new element $\infty$ and declare that $x + \infty = \infty$ for any $x$ (including $\infty$). This works fine (considering only addition for now, no multiplication) except that you lose the ability to subtract; this addition is no longer [cancellative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property), meaning that $x + y = x + z$ no longer implies $y = z$. Formally (ignore this if you don't care), addition only makes $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) rather than a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), and $\infty$ becomes an [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element). But we can still define an order in which $x \le \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and this order still has the property that if $x \le y$ then $x + z \le y + z$; this means we still have an [ordered monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_semigroup).

Now suppose we want to get multiplication in the game. Probably we should ask that $x \cdot \infty = \infty$ for $x > 0$ and in particular for $x = \infty$. But we need to decide what $0 \cdot \infty$ is. If we insist that multiplication continue to [distribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over addition then we need

$$0 \cdot \infty = 0 \cdot (\infty + \infty) = 0 \cdot \infty + 0 \cdot \infty$$

which means the only possible options are that $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ or $\infty$. If we pick $\infty$ then we lose the familiar fact that $0$ times anything is zero. I don't think $0$ is an entirely satisfactory option but let's stick with it for now.

Now we need to decide what $(-1) \cdot \infty$ is. Again, if we insist that multiplication continue to distribute over addition, this requires

$$0 = 0 \cdot \infty = (1 - 1) \cdot \infty = \infty + (-1) \cdot \infty.$$

But with the way we've defined addition this is impossible; there is no element which, when added to $\infty$, produces $0$. The general problem here is that distributivity forces $-1$ to act as the additive inverse, and we already gave that up. So we have a couple different choices here:

- We could give up distributivity. That would be terrible.
- We could add a new element $-\infty$ and declare that $(-1) \cdot \infty = - \infty$ and that $\infty + (-\infty) = 0$. But this breaks [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property): for example, we would have $0 = \infty + (-\infty) = (1 + \infty) + (-\infty) = 1 + (\infty + (-\infty)) = 1$. The lesson is that when we gave up subtraction we *really* gave up subtraction and we shouldn't try to get it back. Subtraction is gone forever.
- We could give up negative numbers. This is actually a perfectly fine thing to do: the non-negative reals $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \cup \{ \infty \}$ together with infinity, addition, and multiplication as defined here is a perfectly well-behaved [ordered semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) (which basically means we can add, multiply, and compare $\le$, but we can't subtract), and the subring consisting of the non-negative integers together with $\infty$ is exactly the ordered semiring given by the at-most-countable [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number).

We have to give up something, though.

Comment: This seems to skip over "$\infty+2>\infty+1$" that Tom requested. But this is a very nice exposition!

Comment: @Mark: in the context of the next line I think the OP's intended meaning is that $\infty + 2 = \infty + 1$ is bad because it would imply $2 = 1$. In the first section I point out that this doesn't have to happen as long as you throw away subtraction. If the OP really wants $\infty + 2$ to be a different entity from $\infty + 1$ then Noah's answer works so here I am presenting a different answer with different features.